# «Не любивший противоречий(,) и в особенности таких»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Из ["Анны Карениной"](https://books.google.ee/books?id=kBYpA51-GJIC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=%E2%80%94%20%D0%92%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=f3HvYowK6r&sig=ACfU3U1Vz5rAWRL20a512NhsXelz_dH18A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTz9yax47pAhVCyKYKHUQKAjcQ6AEwBnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%94%20%D0%92%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5&f=false):

> — Впрочем, — нахмурившись сказал Сергей Иванович, не любивший **противоречий и в особенности** таких, которые беспрестанно перескакивали с одного на другое и без всякой связи вводили новые доводы, так что нельзя было знать, на что отвечать, — впрочем, не в том дело.

Можно ли поставить запятую перед "и в особенности"? Почему ее нет? Мне кажется, конструкция всего лишь уточняет, какие противоречия Сергей Иванович не любил.

Answer (score 1):

[**В особенности**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_94) — это наречие, оно не входит в состав присоединительного оборота, содержащего дополнительные замечания или разъяснения. Здесь нет такого оборота.

Тип противоречий в предложении не уточняется — противоречия не могут беспрестанно перескакивать и вводить новые доводы (это свойственно только человеку).
"В особенности" относится к слову "таких" в значении *тех, таких людей, таких собеседников*. Запятая перед "и" не нужна.

*Не любивший* (чего?) *противоречий и* [не любивший] (кого?) *в особенности таких* (= тех), *которые беспрестанно перескакивали...*

В словаре Ушакова:
[**такой**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1050546)
3. *местоимение, указательное*. В главном предложении, при наличии в придаточном предложении союзов и союзных слов «что», «как», «как будто», «какой» и т. п., употр. для указания на то, что является содержанием придаточного предложения.
*Я таких любить не могу, на которых мне приходится глядеть сверху вниз* (Тургенев).

**Дополнение**
В предложении, приведенном Вами, отсутствует запятая после "нахмурившись". В подавляющем большинстве изданий она есть.

Comment: Прочитал страницу с диалогом, и там действительно Левин перескакивает с одного на другое и "виляет", что и раздражает Сергея Ивановича.

Comment: Я не знаток Толстого, поэтому при первичном прочтении не сразу поняла о чем речь (предложение показалось странным, нелогичным). Мне тоже пришлось перечитать предыдущий текст, чтобы попытаться ответить на вопрос. Возможно, автору надо было дать ссылку — отвечающие бы не рылись в памяти (или в поиске контекста).  P. S. Может, стоит добавить ссылку, как Вы считаете?

Comment: Да, увидел, конечно, так здорово получилось!

Comment: А я нашел без запятой после нахмурившись. Там вроде страница типа фото:   https://ru.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Страница:L._N._Tolstoy._All_in_90_volumes._Volume_18.pdf/272

Comment: А ну ладно, Вы говорите, что в большинстве нет.

Comment: Не-не, наоборот, — запятая преимущественно есть.

Comment: Описался, да всё верно, есть

Answer (score 1):

Видела в Интернете тексты без запятой. И всё-таки, думаю, **запятая перед присоединительной конструкцией нужна:**

***— Впрочем, — нахмурившись, сказал Сергей Иванович, не любивший противоречий, и в особенности таких, которые беспрестанно перескакивали с одного на другое и без всякой связи вводили новые доводы, так что нельзя было знать, на что отвечать, — впрочем, не в том дело.***

1. Союз И здесь **присоединительный**, а **не соединительный**: нельзя употребить конструкцию  *противоречий и таких (противоречий)* как однородные члены.
2. Присоединительная конструкция содержит дополнительные разъяснения высказывания.
3. Характерная особенность присоединительных конструкций - разрыв между ними и основным высказыванием. Поэтому они стоят после длительной паузы и выделяются логически и интонационно. [Сущность присоединения](http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-488.shtml#book_page_top)

У нас основное высказывание  *— Впрочем, — нахмурившись, сказал Сергей Иванович, не любивший противоречий ... - впрочем, не в том дело*. В середине высказывания присоединительная конструкция вносит дополнительное разъяснение.

Впрочем, по этому поводу могут быть разные мнения.